# mariadb 10 uncompress() return blob instead of string

Tags: mysql, mariadb

According to mysql and mariadb [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/functions-and-operators/encryption-functions/uncompress/) uncompress() returns a string if input string was compressed using compress().

Also stated in the examples:

```
SELECT UNCOMPRESS(COMPRESS('a string'));
+----------------------------------+
| UNCOMPRESS(COMPRESS('a string')) |  
+----------------------------------+
| a string                         |
+----------------------------------+
```

However on mysql workbench and navicat i get only a blob as result. Only using

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNCOMPRESS(COMPRESS('a string')) USING utf8);
```

returns the original string. Where I am wrong? Are the docs wrong or am I just misinterpreting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result type of `UNCOMPRESS()` has been `LONG_BLOB` since at least MySQL 5.1, before that it was `VARBINARY`.

Background is that `COMPRESS()` only compresses string contents but does not preserve meta data like character set or collation. So for `UNCOMPRESS()` returning the uncompressed data as a binary data stream is the only safe option. Converting the returned binary data to a specific character set and collation is up to the user, e.g. by storing this information out of band in a separate column and then using it as argument to `CONVERT()` later.

Comment: if i think about it, that totally makes sense. wish i had thought in that direction.